# Modyifying an Instance Variable Outside of a Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, instance-variables

Can anyone tell me how to modify a class or instance variable outside of a class with **only one line**? So, given this code

```
class Dummy
    def initialize()
        @var = 0
    end
    def value
        @var * 2
    end
end

d = Dummy.new
```

I cannot change any of the above. I can only add **one** line so that d.value returns 6. Do any tricks exist to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
d.instance_variable_set("@var", 3)
```

But don't do this in an actual program. `instance_variable_set` is mainly useful for metaprogramming. If you're using it in some other context, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was the wrong way to do it, but that's the way the question was worded. Thanks!

Comment: (Although I'd pass in a symbol these days.)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Heh, true. I'm so used to using strings there (since normally I'm using a dynamically named variable) that I just instictively typed a string even though it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Chuck's answer:

> d.instance_eval{@var = 3}

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dummy; def set_the_stupid_value(val) @var = val end end; d.set_the_stupid_value(3)
```

Voilà, only one line, just like the OP wanted.

Comment: I'm getting a scrollbar underneath. Try `def d.set_the_stupid_value(val) @var = val end; d.set_the_stupid_value(3)`